# canvas.toDataURL() returns black image in some cases

Tags: javascript, canvas, todataurl

Why does calling toDataURL() on a canvas return a solid black image in some cases?

E.g. try this test case:

Open this URL in chrome: https://www.shadertoy.com/embed/Ms23DR

And then type in the js console:

```js
window.open(document.getElementById("demogl").toDataURL("image/png"));
```

It shows a black image, why?

If you go to the [non-embedded page](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Ms23DR) and enter the same javascript, you get the desired image!

What causes the image to be black in the first case?

The reason why I'm asking is because I encountered this problem in my current project where I need to have a way to get the image from the canvas in a way that works in all modern browsers. I thought this way would work.

So I'd appreciate if you could tell me what causes the image to be black in the above test case.

Thanks!

Comment: @Kaiido thanks so much, that was it! `preserveDrawingBuffer: true`.

Comment: Glad it helped, don't hesitate to accept the dupe suggestion in this case, so it goes off of the "to-be-answered" stream.

Comment: How can I accept the duplicate suggestion? I don't see a button or link for that, sorry..

Comment: oh weird, you should have one at top of your question...

Comment: There is the link to the other question in a yellow box ("This question may already have an answer here:"), but I don't see a way to accept it as a duplicate..

Comment: I thought you should have the ["big blue button"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250922/can-we-clarify-to-the-op-that-their-question-is-not-yet-closed-and-the-duplicate/250930#250930)... Maybe a bug with new UI, maybe something I don't know.